# Is it possible to write a function which takes template arguments with different initialisations

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry for the awkward title, it is quite difficult to phrase in words.
What I want to know is:

Suppose I have a template class, such as

```
template<typename T, int height, int width> class GMatrix
```

and I want to overload the * operator in order to multiply to matrices together. Of course the two matrices in question don't need to be of the same width and height, just that the height of the right hand matrix be equal to the width of the left hand matrix.

Essentially I want this kind of functionality to be possible:

```
GMatrix<float, 3, 3> left;
GMatrix<float, 3, 6> right;
GMatrix<float, 3, 6> result = left * right;
```

Is it possible to write such a function? If so, what might the syntax look like for this?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way could be making `operator*` a template function in the dimensions of both operands, like in the following example:

```
template<typename T, int height, int width>
class GMatrix {
};

template<typename T, int h1, int w1, int h2, int w2>
GMatrix<T, h1, w2>
operator*(GMatrix<T, h1, w1> const& a, GMatrix<T, h2, w2> const& b) {
    return GMatrix<T, h1, w2>(); // Or do something else
}

int main() {
    GMatrix<float, 3, 3> left;
    GMatrix<float, 3, 6> right;
    GMatrix<float, 3, 6> result = left * right;
}
```

You could also enforce matrix dimensions at parameter level:

```
template<typename T, int h1, int wh, int w2>
GMatrix<T, h1, w2>
operator*(GMatrix<T, h1, wh> const& a, GMatrix<T, wh, w2> const& b) {
    return GMatrix<T, h1, w2>(); // Or do something else
}
```

Comment: It will be better to omit `h2` as a template parameter to prevent mismatches.

Comment: If you are going to `static_assert`, why bother making it a parameter at all?

Comment: However @Bathsheba has a point here. Using `static_assert` would allow to print a clearer error message, like "matrix dimensions mismatch", instead of 9 kilometers of template garbage. Since it's a static assert, runtime performance won't be affected.

Answer (score 2):

It is, even in the C++03 standard. The prototype you want is

```
template<typename T, int h_left, int w_left, int h_right, int w_right>
GMatrix<T, h_left, w_right>
operator*(const GMatrix<T, h_left, w_left>& left, const GMatrix<T, h_right, w_right>& right);
```

And have a static assertion of `w_left == h_right` for clarity in compilation.